# How to integrate current locatioon in android project mapview balloons

Tags: android, android-mapview, balloon

I'm trying out the info balloon from: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons and it's working perfectly. One thing I'm missing is the ability of setting the current location. Does anybody know how to precisely implement that function?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example I have some url variable which I display in baloon and my onBaloonTap looks like this, where c is context

```
    @Override
  protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
    String url = WebService.upcomigEvent;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    c.startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track position by implementing the LocationListener interface, or by using the MyLocationOverlay class. In both, the method `onLocationChanged` is available, and you can provide it with your own location object that you create, specifying the lat/lng/alt. This in effect 'spoofs' the users location, and this might not be what you want. If you just want to scroll the map to a specific point you can use the `animateTo` method available in the MapController.

Comment: I implemented the LocationListener in MyMap and added the unimplemented methods. In the method onLocationChanged I placed a toast-message. I started the program and simulated a locationchanged by sending a lng/lat value. I expected the toast-message but no. What am I doing wrong maybe something needed to be activated or so?

Comment: I solved it ! I forgot to set LocationManager and LocationListener now it works like a charm. Thanks for the help

Comment: An additional question:
Is it possible to add an url to this balloon, so when I hit that url it opens the browser with the according url? If so how to achieve that?